Why `geom_arc_bar()` width is not uniform ? How to make it the same width everywhere?
From this dataset:
data <- data.frame("type" = c("low_carbon", "high_carbon"), 
                       "start" = c(0, 0.7 * pi),
                       "end" = c(0.7 * pi, pi)
    )

I wanted to make a gauge with ggpllot2 and ggforce
library("ggplot2")
library("ggforce")

Here is the code:
ggplot(data = data) +
      geom_arc_bar(
        mapping = aes(
          x0 = 1,
          y0 = 1,
          fill = type,
          start = start - pi / 2,
          end = end - pi / 2,
          r0 = 0.75,
          r = 1
        )
      ) +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.text = element_text(size = 11))


So i want a width of 0.25 because r - r0 = 1 - 0.75 = 0.25, but as you see the gauge width is not uniform everywhere.
See output plot:

So is it possible to make it the same with everywhere, for example 0.25 ?
Thanks !
I tried to scale differently the y axis, but is there a more elegant way ?

The width in the middle is exactly 0.25. Hold the edge of a piece of paper up to your monitor  along the y = 1.75 gridline and you will see the bottom of the center of the arc just touch it. (or add + geom_hline(yintercept = 1.75) to your plot).

If you want it to appear uniform, you need to make your x and y scales the same with + coord_fixed().

Ah, yes i didn't see that in the center it was between 1.75 and 2 ! Many thanks
